# How do I import the Spark Knowledge Modules in Oracle Data Integrator 12c?

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I need to change the default `LKM File to Spark` Knowledge Module in ODI 12c. Unfortunately, when I try to import it from `/.../odi/sdk/xml-reference/component_kms/spark_python`, nothing appears in the list of Knowledge Modules to import. Knowledge Modules do appear (though the wrong ones) when I look at `/.../odi/sdk/xml-reference/`.

Looking at the structure of the Spark KM XMLs, it appears different to the regular KMs.

Does anyone know if there is a way to import these modules to make it possible to copy/change them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components KM can not be imported / duplicated / modified / deleted. While the template-based KMs are just a template of code that you can edit and fine-tune, components KMs are based on java libraries and act more as black boxes. You can't create your own component KM. An editor for component KMs might be available in the future though.

If you really have to change something in the Spark KM, I guess your only solution is to create a new template-based KM for Spark.